# Definition of "$x$ occurs free as the $i$th symbol in a wff"

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In Enderton's logic book he defines the free variables of a wff recursively as

> 1. For atomic $\alpha$, $x$ occurs free in $\alpha$ iff $x$ occurs in (i.e., is a symbol of) $\alpha$.
> 2. $x$ occurs free in $(¬\alpha)$ iff $x$ occurs free in $\alpha$.
> 3. $x$ occurs free in $(\alpha → \beta)$ iff x occurs free in $\alpha$ or in $\beta$.
> 4. $x$ occurs free in $\forall v_i \alpha$ iff $x$ occurs free in $\alpha$ and $x\neq v_i$ .

But then he has an exercise asking for "a precise definition of what it means for the variable $x$ to occur free as the $i$th symbol in the wff $\alpha$".

Is it just me, or is the definition trivial: $x$ occurs free as the $i$th symbol in $\alpha$ if $x$ occurs free in $\alpha$ and $x$ is the $i$th symbol in $\alpha$.

Are we not able to determine when something is the $i$th symbol? Maybe he wants a recursive definition, but such a definition would start with

> 1. For atomic $\alpha$, $x$ occurs free as the $i$th symbol in $\alpha$ iff $x$ occurs as the $i$th symbol of $\alpha$.

But if we can determine the $i$th symbol of an atomic wff, shouldn't we be able to determine the $i$th symbol of any wff, or for that matter any string (just count). So isn't the recursive definition seemingly pointless? I'm a bit confused about the spirit of this exercise.

Comment: For atomic, it is Ok; but what about $\alpha \to \beta$? If $i$ is $\le$ the number of symbols of $\alpha$, then the clause applies to $\alpha$, but if $i$ is greater than... the clause must consider $\beta$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA But we have already recursively defined what free variables of a wff are. So why is it not sufficient to say $x$ occurs free as the $i$th symbol iff $x$ occurs free and $x$ is the $i$th symbol?

Comment: Surely we do not need a recursive definition to define what it means to be the $i$th symbol, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just realized my mistake. A wff can contain $x$ as both a free and bound variable. For example, in  $\alpha=(\forall x Fx\lor Gx)$, the last $x$ occurs free but $x$ as the 5th symbol is not free. Thus even though $x$ is free in $\alpha$ and $x$ is the 5th symbol, we cannot say "$x$ occurs free as the 5th symbol".